# How can I set header of files that I upload Google Cloud Bucket in browser?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I use Google Cloud Storage for storing and serving JS and image files. I want to learn how can I cache images for these files? Is there any way to do this settings?

(EDIT)

I enabled Google CDN and I set CORS policy but result does not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your website as a static website, [Cloud Storage acts as a CDN](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-dynamic). you can also [set up cache](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache) on your object for invalidate them automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to use Ruby on Rails Gems of Google Cloud and somehow it changed the Google Cloud behavior for cacheing. 

When I checked my image and JS files now they come with "cache-control: private, max-age:0" and this creates the problem.

I try to set CROS policy and use gsutil -m setmeta -r "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" gs://<bucketname>/* in command line but still some files comes with private cache control and I'm not sure how to deal with new files.